# When can you call functions with labeled arguments without the labels?

Tags: function, arguments, ocaml

It seems that in certain situations you can call functions with labeled arguments without the labels if they're in the right order; e.g.

```ml
let f ~x ~y = Format.sprintf "%d %s" x y;;
f 3 "test";;
```

runs successfully, but

```ml
f "test" 3;;
```

fails with the error message

```
Line 1, characters 2-8:
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
         int
```

For functions with optional arguments, it seems to work if you don't pass in the optional arguments:

```ml
let f ?(x = 1) ~y () = Format.sprintf "%d %s" x y;;
f "help" ();;
```

succeeds, but

```ml
f 2 "help" ();;
```

fails with the error message

```
Line 1, characters 4-10:
Error: The function applied to this argument has type
         ?x:int -> y:string -> string
This argument cannot be applied without label
```

Is there a general rule for when this is possible?

Comment: You can usually omit the labels as long as the arguments are passed in the correct order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can omit labels if the application is total (i.e., all *required* arguments are provided) *and* if the return type of the function is not a type variable. Arguments to the optional parameters must always be passed by a label.

Let's do some examples,

```
let example1 ?(opt=0) ~a ~b ~c unlabeled = 
  opt + a + b + c + unlabeled;;

example1 1 2 3 4;;
- : int = 10
```

Here we were able to apply all arguments without labels, because we have provided all required arguments (the optional parameter is not required, hence the name), and the resulting type is not polymorphic. However, if we will take the `List.fold` function from Core or ListLabels, which has type

```
'a list -> init:'accum -> f:('accum -> 'a -> 'accum) -> 'accum
```

Then we will get,

```
List.fold [1;2;3;4] 0 (+);;
- : init:(int -> (int -> int -> int) -> '_weak1) ->
    f:((int -> (int -> int -> int) -> '_weak1) ->
       int -> int -> (int -> int -> int) -> '_weak1) ->
    '_weak1
```

instead of `10`, which one would expect. The reason for that is since the resulting type `'accum` is a type variable, so it could also be a function, e.g., `int -> int` or `string -> int -> unit`, etc -- all those types match with the `'accum` type. That basically means that this function accepts a potentially infinite number of positional arguments. Therefore, all arguments that we provided were interpreted as positional, and as a result, we never were able to fill in the labeled arguments, therefore, our application wasn't made total. This actually makes our original definition of the rule at the beginning of the posting redundant - since an application, which type is denoted with a type variable, could never be total.

Note, that this problem only occurs when the return type is a type variable, not just includes some type variables, for example, we can easily omit labels with the `List.map` function, e.g, given `List.map` from Core, which has type

```
'a list -> f:('a -> 'b) -> 'b list
```

we can easily apply it

```
# List.map [1;2;3] ident;;
- : int Core_kernel.List.t = [1; 2; 3]
```

With all that being said, it is usually assumed a bad practice to omit the labels. Mainly because of the caveats with polymorphic return types and because it makes the order of the labeled arguments important, which is sort of counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a general rule for this. From [the manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lablexamples.html):

> Formal parameters and arguments are matched according to their respective labels, the absence of label being interpreted as the empty label. This allows commuting arguments in applications. One can also partially apply a function on any argument, creating a new function of the remaining parameters.
>
> If several arguments of a function bear the same label (or no label), they will not commute among themselves, and order matters. But they can still commute with other arguments.
>
> As an exception to the above parameter matching rules, **if an application is total (omitting all optional arguments), labels may be omitted.** In practice, many applications are total, so that labels can often be omitted.

Comment: Interesting, it seems like for a function like `let f ~x = let s = 1 in fun ~y ~z -> Format.sprintf "%d %d %s %s" x s y z;;` you have to apply the arguments in the second function as well. I guess you have to apply arguments until the returned value is no longer a function?

Comment: Yes, because OCaml is a curried language there are only single argument (1-ary) functions. What appears to be multi-argument functions is actually just syntax sugar for `fun a -> fun b -> ...`. Total application therefore means that arguments have been applied until the returned value is known to not be a function.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense, but I'm not super clear about the rules for this; e.g. if one of the arguments is also a function, this doesn't seem like it always holds true. `let f ~s ~t = s ~r:t;;` then `f (fun ~r -> r) 3;;` is not equal to `f ~s:(fun ~r -> r) ~t:3;;`, but rather, it seems like it's partially applying the arguments to `s`, so `s` has type `r:'a -> (r:'b -> 'b) -> int -> 'c`.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely an interesting one, but it seems to make sense. You seem to assume that the compiler wants to achieve total application, and you might also think that `fun ~r -> r` should match up with `~s` because `~s` needs an `~r`, but they don't have to and they don't so so here. Since it's possible that `~s` _can_  return a function, the total application rule does not apply. And since the applied arguments aren't labeled `~s` or `~t`, they must therefore belong to the function returned by `s`.

Comment: Hence `~s` is a function that takes an `~r` with whatever is passed as`~t` to the outermost function,  and a _different_ function that also happens to take an `~r`, and an `int`. Here's an application which fits that: `f (fun ~r -> r) 3 ~s:(fun ~r _ _ -> r) ~t:4`. This will return whatever the last function returns, which in this case is an `int`.